# /question/unanswered, what exactly does it give?

Tags: support

It says no upvoted answers? Does that mean no accepted answers or no answers which have a positive vote? I'm kind of confused about the whole /answered result.

I'm trying to get questions with 0 answers using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation should be taken literally, i.e. your second interpretation *no answers which have a positive vote* is correct! This is in line with how the [Unanswered](https://stackapps.com/unanswered) tab is handled, see [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)

> I'm trying to get questions with 0 answers using the API.

You could start off from the `/questions/unanswered` route, from its result set you'll 'simply' need to filter out all those answers where the `answer_count` field is 0.

How 'simple' the latter really is depends on the client stack in use of course, i.e. you might be able to include the filter criteria in your request already, but otherwise you should always be able to search through the raw result array.

Comment: ok thanks, is there a way to search for questions with zero answers. Realy it would be great if you filter the API by any field the API returns.

Comment: @Jonathan - that would be an obvious and welcome addition on the API level indeed; right now you'll need to do this manually or with the help of the particular client stack in use, see my extended answer on how to approach this.

Comment: The only problem with your extended answer is that if I download 25 questions sometimes there will be only 15 question truly answered other times there will be 20which is inconsistent. I could always over download  but there'd be no guarantee and it use more bandwidth and time

Comment: @Jonathan - indeed: there are several such limitations/shortcomings as of API v1 and quite some posts with similar issues accordingly; you'll have to ask the ones in charge for the API design (i.e. mainly Kevin Montrose) for the rationale in case, see e.g. his answer to [Why is there no /answers route?](http://stackapps.com/questions/1660/1661#1661); while I would have designed many things different myself as well, you'll need to account for this being a v1 - revisiting all these issues is one of the reasons why I recently asked about the [API evolution](http://stackapps.com/questions/1804) ;)